# How do i allow blank fields to be accepeted by my database as null?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a simple html form and a php file.  The form works fine and when every field is filled out the form successfully submits the data to my database...but when i submit the form with an blank empty field i get an error saying that field was not received.  How do i get my database to accept a blank field as null?

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="/tst/contact_form.php" class="well" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" novalidate="">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="75" width="653">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls"><input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" id="name" name="itemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME" required="" type="text" /></div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls"><input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number" id="phone" name="qty" placeholder="QTY" required="" type="text" /></div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls"><textarea id="txta" cols="25" style="height: 23px;" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your question/concern" id="msg" name="notes" placeholder="NOTES" required="" rows="6" type="msg"></textarea></div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls"><input class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" id="email-address" name="stotal" placeholder="TOTAL" required="" type="text" /></div>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls submit-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></div>
</div>
</form>
```

**contact_form.php**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

if($_POST['itemname']){
    $itm = $_POST['itemname'];
}else{
    echo "Item Name not received";
    exit;
}
if($_POST['qty']){
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
}else{
    echo "Qty not received";
    exit;
}
if($_POST['stotal']){
    $stotal = $_POST['stotal'];
}else{
    echo "Suggested Total not received";
    exit;
}
if($_POST['notes']){
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
}else{
    echo "notes not received";
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (itemname, qty, stotal, notes) 
        VALUES ('$itm', '$qty', '$stotal', '$notes')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
```

http://oi58.tinypic.com/sotwjq.jpg

Comment: The problem is not the script per se, but the database schema. Post your table structure (the CREATE TABLE statement). You can mark a column as allowing null or not -- if you're getting a database error about null columns, then your schema does not allow null there. Either a) modify the schema, or b) supply defaults for missing values (like an empty string)

Comment: set your values default to null

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/sotwjq.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your DB fields should allow `NULL` values

OR

You should put some place holder values for the fields if you do not get them from the form.

e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['notes'])) {
  $notes = $_POST['notes'];
}
else {
  $notes = '';
}
```

And use `$notes` for DB purpose.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the db column from not null

```
ALTER TABLE supplier
  MODIFY supplier_name
varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table Name]
ALTER COLUMN [column name] varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove statements like

```
if ($_POST['somevar']) {
    $somevar = $_POST['somevar'];
} else {
    echo "somevar not received";
    exit;
}
```

and write them directly

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (itemname, qty, stotal, notes) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST['itemname']."', '".$_POST['qty']."', '".$_POST['stotal']."', '".$_POST['notes']."')";
```

then every empty var will be inserted in database as empty string `''`

and if you need exactly `NULL`

1. check your columns for `DEFAULT NULL` as [@tlindell says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26986508/1713660)
2. use `$somevar = $_POST['somevar'] ? $_POST['somevar'] : 'NULL';`

Answer (score 0):

Set Your Database to allow null values. Eg: `MEMBER_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly checking for empty fields and rejecting them. You need to change your validation:

```
if (isset($_POST['notes'])) {

  // escaped and added quotes
  $notes = "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['notes'])."'";
}
else {
  $notes = "NULL;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (itemname, qty, stotal, notes) 
    VALUES ($itm, $qty, $stotal, $notes)";
```

When you generate your query this should give you properly quoted and escaped values, or the NULL keyword. Your database schema should have the columns set to accept NULL values too.

Note: You should escape user input to avoid SQL inection. Actually, you should use prepared statements, but that's another question

Note: an empty string `''` is not the same as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late update but I've had some new findings on the matter based on tests derived from this post. I've found that trying to use a variable set to null doesn't seem to work with the most current version of mysql. I'm using XAMPP as a test server. I attempted to set the variable and those all failed to take effect. So it seems the most effective way to set a field to null would be to write a query that does this directly, for example.

```
    $query="UPDATE groups
               SET reimbursementamount=NULL,
                   reimbursement=0
               WHERE groupID=:groupID";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $params = array(':groupID' => $groupID);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return true;
```

Using this format I was able to successfully set the field to null based on if the field was empty and a checkbox for reimbursement was as well. $adminrepay is the amount the admin should receive if $adminreimbursement which is a checkbox is checked.

```
            if($_POST['adminrepay'] == 0.00)
            {
                $reimbursement = 0;
                $adminrepay = 0;
            }
            elseif(empty($_POST['adminreimbursement']))
            {
                $reimbursement = 0;
                $adminrepay = 0;
            }
            elseif(!empty($_POST['adminreimbursement']) OR !empty($_POST['adminrepay']))
            {
                $reimbursement = 1;
                $adminrepay = trim($_POST['adminrepay']);
                $adminrepay = strip_tags($adminrepay);
                $adminrepay = htmlspecialchars($adminrepay);                    
            }
```

If $adminreimbursement is not checked then it will run the above query to set the field to null. Wasn't very efficient but it did the job. Hope this helps anyone with this issue.

NOTE: NULL needs to be capitalized, didn't seem to accept null in lowercase either.